# What is the difference between SGX and TPM?

Tags: tpm, intel-sgx

What is the difference between Intel Guard Extensions (SGX) and Trusted Module Platform (TPM)?

This [answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/175749/what-are-the-functional-similarities-and-difference-between-tpm-and-sgx-in-trust) tells you what the similarities are and what the features are, but not explicitly what the differences are.

Comment: Actually, it does talk a lot about the differences. If it is not meeting your needs, can you explain more about what you are looking for?

Comment: There are a lot of differences because they are two totally different technologies.

Comment: In my opinion the answer tells you only what the features are. I can't really make out the differences. Could you tell me the three main differences between them?

Comment: @user199561 Did you read the duplicate though? It explains the _differing_ features. The two technologies are very, very different so the differences are vast. Three random examples? 1) There are many implementations of TPM, but only one of SGX (Intel's implementation). 2) TPM does not execute bytecode from the computer, whereas SGX enclaves do. 3) SGX is unique to Intel, whereas TPM can also be used by AMD or even ARM.

Comment: @forest and what are the functional differences?

Comment: @user199561 That is also explained in the answer. TPM is designed for attestation, whereas SGX is designed for tamper-prevention, for example.